# What is attribute " createdDateTime " indicates in Mail message?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, message, delta

I'm currently working with mailbox messages using Graph API. I want to know what does the time in attribute "createdDateTime" indicates?. I'm finding that the attribute "sentDateTime" is ahead for few seconds or equal to "createdDateTime" for a mailbox message.

Graph API response of message:

"createdDateTime": "2021-06-17T13:02:**21**Z"

"sentDateTime": "2021-06-17T13:02:**22**Z"

Another response:

"createdDateTime": "2021-06-15T01:56:**13**Z"

"sentDateTime": "2021-06-15T01:56:**13**Z"

Another response:

"createdDateTime": "2021-06-15T01:52:**30**Z"

"sentDateTime": "2021-06-15T01:52:**15**Z"

Answer (score 0):

It stands for the date and time of item creation. It seems items were sent out automatically by any software or macros.

Comment: No, it's a user sent mails, I tried with my own mailbox also and the times look the same. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a race condition. One states the date/time the message was sent over the wire, the other is the date/time the message was written to Exchange. If there is any delay between these two events, it could easily cause the two values to look like they're a full second off.

I say "looks like" because the resolution here is only to a second. If you increased the resolution to factional seconds, I suspect you'd find `T13:02:21` was moments from flipping over to `T13:02:22`. In other words, they may actually only be fractionally apart rather than a full second.

Comment: Thanks. But In few cases, the time difference is more upto few seconds (added response to the question).  what causes such huge time difference between createdDateTime and sentDateTime?

Comment: Any latency in sending or writing to disc could cause this. Eg, a message is sent right away but a heavy load resulted in the write operation being delayed. These types of discrepancies are pretty par for the course with distributed asynchronous services like Exchange.